# Log into JavaScript login form requests

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to log into [this](https://www.lovoo.com) website that uses a JS based form. Is this even possible with the Python requests library?

```
payload = {
    '_username': 'xxx@xxx.com',
    '_password': 'xxx',
    '_remember_me': 'false'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.lovoo.com/login_check', data=payload)
    r = s.get('https://www.lovoo.com/list/visits')
    print(r.text)
```

I search `r.text` afterwards with grep, but I see I am still not logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an initial get to set some cookies and add some headers:

```
head = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",

}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get("https://www.lovoo.com")
    p = s.post('https://www.lovoo.com/login_check', data=payload, headers=head)
    r = s.get('https://www.lovoo.com/list/visits')
```

If you print *p.json()* you will see a response like `{"referer":"https:\/\/www.lovoo.com\/welcome\/login","success":true,"user":{}}` which means you have successfully logged in.